# Работа приложения из offline

Tags: java, android, сеть

Есть приложение которое взаимодействует с сервером.

Работает примерно так: юзер при взаимодействии с приложением изменяет свой прогресс, этот прогресс должен быть отправлен на сервер каждый раз как изменяется в ответ сервер отдает инфу о состоянии на сервере и после этого клиент должен опять отправить запрос и забрать нужную информацию с сервера.

В принципе, ничего сложного, до того момента пока юзер находится все время в `online` . Но такое может быть не всегда, и возможно что юзер выполнит некие задачи в приложении `offline` - его прогресс соответственно измениться, и как только появиться интернет нужно сразу выполнить запросы на сервер - `отправить прогресс` и `забрать новые данные`. Я в данный момент делаю это с помощью `GCM NetworkManager`, но задачи созданные с его помощью не всегда выполняются в тоже время в которые должны были выполниться. Так же видел варианты с `Sync Adapter` , но он работает с контент провайдерам и `SQLite` насколько я понял, а я использую `Realm`. Вопрос как лучше организовать нужную мне схему работы приложения?

Comment: а если слушать броадкаст на появление сети и запускать таску у `GCM Network Manager`?

Comment: да я думал об этом, но это не существенно отличается от того что  я имею сейчас.